# jquery and input selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JS Fiddle of nonworking code :
https://jsfiddle.net/8fo28ccL/

With the code below, I have items that are dynamically added to my html body whenever a user clicks a button to add a line.  The top line works just fine(its a checkbox), but I cannot get the select input lines to work....

```
var addNewRow = function(id){
html = '<tr id="tr_'+i+'">';
html += '<td><input class="case" id="caseNo_'+i+'" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td class="prod_c"><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][product_id]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
html +='<span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_'+i+'"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>';
html +='</td>';

html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][productName]"  id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][price]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';

html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][quantity]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="stock_'+i+'"/>';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_'+i+'" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][stockMaintainer]" />';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_'+i+'"/>';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_'+i+'"/>';
html += '</td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][staged]" id="staged_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][location]" id="location_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
html += '<option value="Used">Used</option>';
html += '<option value="RTS">RTS</option>';
html += '<option value="LAJ">LAJ</option>';
html += '</select></td>';
html += '</tr>';

if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
    $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
}else{
    $('table').append(html);
}
```

Edit : Sorry, added an old revision of code, updated with the proper TD elements.  The select box will appear on the page, but if you try to select values, nothing saves...

Edit 2 : Guys/Gals, the issue is not whether the html appears in my body(it does via the append function, the issue is AFTER it is added.  After the text is added, a checkbox appears, and a form select field.  If you select a different option in the form select, and save the form, that option is NOT saved.

Comment: Could you show a bit more of the code? See [MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) A side note: the `<input>` is wrapped in a table cell `<td>` and the select box isn't.

Comment: @Steven could you please provide the jquery code that you have tried already ?

Comment: you have to use $(html).appendTo("body"); after those lines

Comment: @clement that is in the code, and everything appends to fine, everything appears to fine, the "staged" td input will save its fields in the database, but the select values are not saved

Comment: @Steven _"If you select a different option in the form select, and save the form, that option is NOT saved."_ Can indicate where this occurs at `js` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfidle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 here is my jsfiddle(new to this) : https://jsfiddle.net/8fo28ccL/

Comment: my godness what a messy code

Comment: @clement Tried to clean up the code a bit, I dont know if jsfiddle saves the tab/space edits or not, hopefully it does...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `var` before `html` , adjusting `+=` to `=` at first `html` variable reference

```js
var i = 0;
var html = '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][staged]" id="staged_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][location]" id="location_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
html += '<option value="Used">Used</option>';
html += '<option value="RTS">RTS</option>';
html += '<option value="LAJ">LAJ</option>';
html += '</select></td>';
document.body.innerHTML = html
```

Comment: I tried that, and it broke my existing code.  All of my snippets prior to "invoice detail location" work perfect

Comment: @Steven Not certain what requirement is ?

Answer (score 0):

From those stuff you provided i can suggest only this things. You should try once.

```
var html = "";
html += "<td><input type='checkbox' name='data[InvoiceDetail][0][staged]' id='staged_1'" + i + " class='form-control autocomplete_txt' autocomplete='off'></td>";
html += "<td><select value='' name='data[InvoiceDetail][0][location]' id='location_1'" + i + "'class='form-control autocomplete_txt' autocomplete='off'>";
html += "<option value='Used'>Used</option>";
html += "<option value='RTS'>RTS</option>";
html += "<option value='LAJ'>LAJ</option>";
html += "</select></td>";
$(html).appendTo(WhereYouwanttoappend);
```

Hope it may work for you.

Comment: The issue is not with the data being added, its with the data added by this script not allowing changes to the select value, to save in the database

Comment: Then you might need to check the code which is passing this 'html' xml to the database I.E. connection string or query you wrote or the url

Answer (score 0):

your html wasn't initialised (probably)

`var html = ''`

check out this running code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvOaqj

Comment: sorry if i have repeated other answers... I didn't refresh before posting

Comment: html was initialized, lines are adding to body correctly, values just are not being saved to database for added lines corresponding to "location"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "value" attribute from your select element.